# Running wp_query for each query runs fine, but if I merge them I get all posts returned for an invalid keyword

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm using wp_query to query posts. The first query searches posts by keyword. The second query will search for posts whose categories are based on that same keyword. When I run each query individually, it works fine for all test cases. However when I merge the two, it will return ALL posts if I enter an invalid keyword (i.e. 'abcdefg'). I would expect it to return the 'not found' message if nothing is found, which it is doing if running each query individually.

Here is what I have:

```
$args1 = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  's' => $search_field_value,
);

// Search categories with keyword
$matching_categories = get_terms('category', array('name__like' => $search_field_value));

$category_ids = array();
foreach ($matching_categories as $category) {
    $category_ids[] = $category->term_id;
}

$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',   // Search in posts
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $category_ids,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);

$query_args1 = new WP_Query($args1);
$query_args2 = new WP_Query($args2);

// Merge two queries together
$merged_posts = array_merge($query_args1->posts, $query_args2->posts);
$merged_posts = array_unique($merged_posts, SORT_REGULAR);

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'post__in' => wp_list_pluck($merged_posts, 'ID'), // Extract post IDs from the merged array
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) { 
    // Do the loop stuff
} else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you're doing anything wrong? What puzzles you specifically?

Comment: @hakre - Everything is working fin, except for when I expect a 'not found' scenario. In other words, keyword search is returning results as I'd expect for posts that exist, but if I enter in 'abcdefg' and execute a search, it returns ALL posts. I would expect it to return the 'not found' message.

Comment: Perhaps you want to review what `$args` is right before new `WP_Query($args)` is being created?